# Executing tsc runs server

Tags: typescript

another typescript related problem which I cannot grasp fully.

When I run `tsc`it should only "compile" (and transpile) the code right?

I have an express server which starts listening when the file is imported (see below).

My question is WHY is the port exposed already when I run `tsc`?

edit: with Port exposed I mean that lsof -i :8080 (8080 is what `app.get("port")` returns) does not return empty, meaning a process is using port 8080, although I just built.

the full command is: `tsc` afterwards the port is blocked as described above.

Does anybody know and can explain?

server.ts:

```
import errorHandler from "errorhandler";

import app from "./app";
...

/**
 * Error Handler. Provides full stack - remove for production
 */
app.use(errorHandler());

/**
 * Start Express server.
 */
const server = app.listen(app.get("port"), () => {
  console.log(
    "  App is running at http://localhost:%d in %s mode",
    app.get("port"),
    app.get("env")
  );
  console.log("  Press CTRL-C to stop\n");
});

const io = require("socket.io")(server);

io.on("connection", (socket: SocketIO.Socket) => {
 ...
});

export { server, io };
```

Comment: What is the full tsc command you are calling? Also, I have a hard time understanding your "port exposed" question. Is this more of a server question?

Comment: edited my request